# Why is eth0 responding to ip-address assigned to ethernet gadget usb0?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ip-address, routing-table

We configure networking on an embedded Linux system by setting one static IP-Address(169.254.0.1/16=LLA) on an Ethernet-Gadget/usb0 while using DHCP on Ethernet/eth0(192.168./16).

To our surprise the embedded system responds on eth0 to the static ip-address. ifconfig on the embedded linux device shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <snip>
          inet addr:192.168.51.156 Bcast:192.168.55.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          <snip>
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <snip>
          inet addr:169.254.0.1  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          <snip>
```

The routing table on the embedded linux device :

```
root@my_embedded_system01:~# ip route
default via 192.168.50.30 dev eth0  proto dhcp  src 192.168.51.156  metric 1024
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.0.1 linkdown
192.168.48.0/21 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.51.156
192.168.50.30 dev eth0  proto dhcp  scope link  src 192.168.51.156  metric 1024
```

Is there a setting on the embedded device which can change that?

Comment: It responded to which static address? How did you check which way the response was handled?

Comment: Multiple of  these embedded systems are connected via eth0 in our local network. I connect with ssh 169.254.0.1 to one of these systems. None is connected via USB.

Comment: So neither is that particular one connected by USB? Maybe your embedded devices to have routing enabled and for some reason your local workstation has a route for them?

Comment: Yes, I dont know how the routing table above would allow that. The ip-address assigned to the Ethernet Gadget is even a local-link address. To my understanding that should not be routed at all.

Comment: And a problem only occurs when we connect one embedded system to USB and then try to connect with ssh. On a computer which is also connected to more of our systems via Ethernet the ssh 169.254.0.1 will get arbitrarily the response of any of the connected systems, not necessarily the one connected to USB.

Comment: A device that has routing enabled (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) should be able to just route between directly connected networks. You would need to check your workstations routing table to check whenever it has a suitable entry for the 169 network. If it does you would need to figure out why it does. There are no link local addresses for IPv4 as there are in IPv6. APIPA addresses are mostly handled just like normal IPs and such can be routable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a firewall. One simple iptables rule will block all packets to usb0 address unless they actually enter through usb0:

```
-d 169.254.0.0/16 ! -i usb0 -j REJECT
```

---

Generally, tere are two separate issues here:

1. Responding to ARP queries for an IP address that belongs to another interface.
2. Accepting IP packets meant for IP addresses that belong to another interface.

The first part can be avoided easily by changing the [net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) sysctl to 1. Afaik, it defaults to 0 because on some operating systems, in IPv4, the addresses are considered to belong to the entire host instead of specific interfaces (weak host model), though it's a bit strange.

The second part (accepting IP packets through any interface) is normal for multi-network (multihomed) hosts. To prevent it, use firewall rules. Both iptables and nft support checking the inbound interface.

Comment: 1. is no problem. For 2.: The embedded system has no iptables2 installed yet. Is there a way to have the tables set-up with "ip route" or "route"?